# PyQt DLL missing when using python.exe but works with anaconda prompt, why?

Tags: python, dll, pyqt

I tried to develop some GUI using PyQt5. 
I used pip (pip, pip3, pip3.7 or installer, I tried older version of PyQt5 as explain in some answer for similar issue but that doesn't help) to install pyQt on my system, but I encounter this error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable.
```

Several topics solve this issue by installing anaconda or other similar python env.
and it works that is true.

But I wonder why when I use anaconda prompt, 
python is able to find every dll when doing

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
```

but not if I use :

C:\Users\ME\Anaconda3\python.exe
or my standard python.exe. 
(and adding the dlls in the root folder of python does not help)
For some reasons, I need to use the anaconda prompt.

I saw that anaconda prompt use a batch file where it seems to add path in my env. variable. 
So did I, by adding :

```
\Library\mingw-w64\bin
\Library\usr\bin
\Library\bin
\Scripts
\bin
```

but that still does not solve this issue. 
What should I do, to make my standard powershell or standard python in cmd window, find the places of the needed dlls ? I don't want to use anaconda prompt on a daily basis.
There must be a way to solve that, isn't it?

Thank you,

Regards,

Comment: Normally the qt binaries path is added to PATH during PyQt5's `__init__.py`. Maybe you can get closer to the problem by just doing an `import PyQt5` and then checking `os.environ["PATH"]` for anything suspicious.

Comment: thank you @Jeronimo for you answer, using os.environ["PATH"] I could see that both environment variables (from both prompt) are identical but I still get the error.
The only difference is the order, it appears that in anaconda, paths (Anaconda3/Library etc...) appears way on top of the list.

In my case even if i put them directly on top of the Windows environment variable windows, they doesn't appear in first.

I guess we can conclude it doesn't come from the environment variables